# Extracting URL text from TextView with Linkify

Tags: android, url, onclick, textview, linkify

I am trying to get the URL text from a link when it is pressed/clicked on and store it into a string. The reason is there are different types of URL's that I am working with that is in the text. The text comes from a JSON into a database stored into the system. When I click a link, it just opens a browser so I need to have it do something else depending on the URL. I assume I do something in the onClick method. Right now I have this in my class:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_video, container, false);

        tvBody = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.body);
        tvBody.setClickable(true);
        tvBody.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        Linkify.addLinks(tvBody, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        tvBody.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return mRoot;
    }    

    OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v == mRoot.findViewById(R.id.body)) {

            }

        }

    };
```

Comment: you. should study the docs about Spanned interface and class URLSpan

Comment: I don't know where the location of the hyperlink is.
It's a block of text with different locations of hyperlinks.

Comment: first call tv.gerText() and see what class instance  it returns, it should help

Comment: wont it return the whole body of text?

Comment: what is returned class instance? did you check it?